# Convert Date datatype to datetime datatype and add static time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm at my wits end... Hope you all can help. I have a date column `entryexpire` in sql table, eg:

```
2013-04-12
```

I need to convert it to a `datetime` with all values in `entryexpire` to have `24:00:00` appended to new values, eg:

```
2103-04-12 24:00:00
```

I've tried cast, covert, adding new columns and concatenation ... All failed me.

Comment: What database are you using? SQL Server/MySQL/Oracle? and `24:00:00` is actually `00:00:00` in most databases.

Comment: You want to change the type of the column, or you just need to SELECT from it and convert to datetime on the fly?

Comment: Im using sql server 2008 and vb.net and trying to pass the query string through vb.net to accomplish.  i would be fine with 00:00:00 also unlimit, didnt realize 24:00:00 was a problem, thanks.  also janos i havent been able to convert to datetime because there is no time associated with it.  if i can convert it and add a time that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Add new column col2 (Datetime). Issue update:

```
update table t1 set col2 = cast(col1, datetime) // db specific function
```

Drop column Col1.
Rename col2 to col1

I mean, there are few other ways of doing it as well

Answer (score 0):

24:00:00 is not really an option for a date - you'd be into the next day. Here's a select statement you can use to tailor a date to your needs, but about the closest you will get to the end of the day is 23:59:59.997

```
   DECLARE @MYDATE varchar(50) = '2013-04-12'

   SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,DATEADD(Ms,-2, CAST(@MYDATE AS DATETIME)))
```

This returns 2013-04-12 23:59:59.997

Alternately, you could have two different varchar columns (which it seems you tried), and query them like this to get a datetime

```
DECLARE @MYDATE varchar(50) = '2013-04-12'
declare @mytime varchar(50) = ' 23:59:59.998'

select CAST(@mydate + @mytime as datetime)
```

Again, using 23:59:59.999 causes the select to return 2013-04-13 00:00:00.000. Not sure why.

Comment: Probably because `datetime`s are only supposed to be able to go up to [23:59:59.997](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).  Please read [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) - I'd avoid attempting to add an 'end-of-day' value; if the OP really needs such a thing, they'd be best off storing the actual next day, and using it as an exclusive upper bound (...which is what the value should be anyways, really).

Comment: @folksymAndrew what im really trying to do is convert and add information from my date column and make it date time with 00:00:00
something like this but i know its wrong:
`convert (datetime,[date_datatype_column],121)+ ' ' + '00:00:00'`
and have it either inserted into a new column or update the original date column, either would work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone had same problem this is how i solved. I created a char column
`temptime`
and added a value of 23:59:00 to all records in database into that column with an update command.

i then created another column as datetime
`entryexpiredatetime`

with my `entryexpiredate` as a char and `temptime` as char column i used @folksymAndrews code as follows:

> Blockquote

`update [table] set entryexpiredatetime = CAST(ENTRYEXPIREDATE+timetime as datetime)`

> Blockquote

then i dropped `temptime` column and was left with my original entryexpiredate and my needed entryexpiredatetime columns.

Thanks for all your help.  This was the best way i felt i could accomplish the task but im sure there is a less invasion way.